# Can "current" on its own be used as a heading, in the sense 'going on'?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, headlinese

I'm translating a webpage, containing a section with news, upcoming events etc. In the original, this section is headed by a single word meaning 'current'. On other webpages like this one this heading has been translated with just that – *current* – but I can't help feeling that it seems odd in English. I'd rather translate it with, for instance, *Going on*.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I right in thinking that *Current* doesn't really work here?
2. If the answer to 1. is yes, what would be a better choice? Would *Going on* work, or are there other solutions that would be more idiomatic? (*News* doesn't work, because that's already used as a subheading)
3. Is there a general rule that can be applied here? Somehow I have a vague feeling that single adjectives aren't readily used in this way in English, (the way they are in my own language), but I haven't been able to find any proper support for this feeling.

Comment: We need more information.  Maybe the names of the other sections would work.  There is no rule against using adjectives as titles *when the context supports it*.  If I had a list of events, I could title sections: "Past", "Upcoming", "Canceled".

Comment: @Juhasz Thanks! So I guess my intuition is just wrong then :) It's a webpage for a school; each class has their own webpage with one section on homework, one on teachers, one on students and so on – including the section I'm talking about in my OP. But you're saying "Current" would work, and that it'd be better/more idiomatic than, for instance, "Going on"?

Comment: There *is* a more idiomatic version of "going on," **ongoing**. But note, it has a meaning of "still in progress," and doesn't apply if anything that is "completed" would appear under the heading. It's possible that "news" is actually the best heading.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks! Yes, I get that that only works for things that actually **are** going on :) I think I'll go with that then, thanks! ("News" is alreadt 'taken', so I can't use that)

Comment: @AndyBonner You agree then that "Current" is not idiomatic?

Comment: @Helen Yes, I've seen the sort of section you describe on many websites, but never seen it labeled "Current," and wouldn't choose that myself. Now that I've thought about it, I think maybe it's because it's an adjective, and such headings are more often plural nouns. I've seen "Updates" for such a section often. For a conversational tone, "What's new" could be good.

Comment: @AndyBonner – Yes!! That was exactly my point/my intuition (see (3) in the OP) :))) And yes, I thought about "What's new" as well, but thought that would be too close to "News"... Anyway – tusen tack för hjälpen!! (Literal translation: 'A thousand thanks for the help' (Swedish)) :)